# Change table cell highlight for first 3 rows

Tags: css, css-tables

I have this table with row highlighting – it highlights the rows in different colours (first 3 in dark and later in blue). I wonder If I can also change the table cell highlight to yellow for the first three rows and keep the rest as it is now?
Here is the style:

```
<style>
body {
    background-color: #0D0D0D;
}

tr:hover{
    background: #0000F7;
    color: rgb(102,102,102);
}


tr:hover td{
  background: transparent !important;
}

tr td:hover {
    background-color: #609 !important;
}

tr:nth-child(1):hover {
    background-color: #292C31;
}

tr:nth-child(2):hover {
    background-color: #292C31;
}
tr:nth-child(3):hover {
    background-color: #292C31;
}

a {
    color:#BFBFBF !important;   
}

a {
text-decoration:none !important;
}


</style>
```

And the file itself: 
https://jsfiddle.net/33bxg04e/

Comment: DO YOU THINK YOU CAN ALSO HELP ME ADD THE RED BORDER TO THE HIGHLIGHTED TABLE CELLS IN THE UPPER 3 ROWS?

Answer (score 3):

You can add this to your CSS:

```
tr:nth-child(-n+3) td:hover {
    background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

this sets the cells (td) in the first 3 rows (tr) to have a yellow background color.

I also suggest simplifying your current CSS and changing:

```
tr:nth-child(1):hover {
    background-color: #292C31;
}

tr:nth-child(2):hover {
    background-color: #292C31;
}
tr:nth-child(3):hover {
    background-color: #292C31;
}
```

to :

```
tr:nth-child(-n+3):hover {
    background-color: #292C31;
}
```

Updated JSFiddle-
https://jsfiddle.net/33bxg04e/4/

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can.

Remove the `!important`s from your CSS and add this:

```
tr td:hover {
    background-color: #609;
}

tr:nth-child(1) td:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}

tr:nth-child(2) td:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
tr:nth-child(3) td:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/33bxg04e/2/)

Comment: do you think the row highlight can be changes to just WHITE BORDER SURROUNDING ALL OF THE active row?

Answer (score 0):

```css
body {
    background-color: #0D0D0D;
}

tr:hover{
 background: #292C31;
 color: rgb(102,102,102);
}


tr:hover td{
  background: transparent;
}
tr td:hover {
 background-color: yellow;
}

tr:nth-child(1n + 4):hover {
  background-color: #0000F7;
}
tr:nth-child(1n + 4) td:hover {
  background-color: #609;
}


a {
 color:#BFBFBF !important; 
}

a {
text-decoration:none !important;
}
```

```html
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">

<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-5">
<meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Excel 14">
<link rel=File-List href="Sheet1_filelist.xml">
<style id
<style id="17540223 12ii44_765_Styles">
<!--table
 {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\.";
 mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\,";}
.xl1521017
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:black;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:0;
 mso-number-format:General;
 text-align:general;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 mso-background-source:auto;
 mso-pattern:auto;
 white-space:nowrap;}
.xl6421017
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:white;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:0;
 mso-number-format:General;
 text-align:general;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 border:.5pt solid windowtext;
 background:#0D0D0D;
 mso-pattern:black none;
 white-space:nowrap;}
.xl6521017
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:white;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:0;
 mso-number-format:General;
 text-align:general;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 border:.5pt solid windowtext;
 background:#595959;
 mso-pattern:black none;
 white-space:nowrap;}
-->
</style>
<title>Sheet1</title>
</head>

<body>
<!--[if !excel]>&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->
<!--The following information was generated by Microsoft Excel's Publish as Web
Page wizard.-->
<!--If the same item is republished from Excel, all information between the DIV
tags will be replaced.-->
<!----------------------------->
<!--START OF OUTPUT FROM EXCEL PUBLISH AS WEB PAGE WIZARD -->
<!----------------------------->

<div id="17540223 12ii44_765" align=center x:publishsource="Excel">

<h1 style='color:black;font-family:Calibri;font-size:14.0pt;font-weight:800;
font-style:normal'>Sheet1</h1>

<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=336 style='border-collapse:
 collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:336pt'>
 <col width=48 span=7 style='width:48pt'>
 <tr height=15 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=15 class=xl6421017 width=48 style='height:15.0pt;width:48pt'>A</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 width=48 style='border-left:none;width:48pt'>A</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 width=48 style='border-left:none;width:48pt'>A</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 width=48 style='border-left:none;width:48pt'>A</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 width=48 style='border-left:none;width:48pt'>A</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 width=48 style='border-left:none;width:48pt'>A</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 width=48 style='border-left:none;width:48pt'>A</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=15 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=15 class=xl6421017 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>B</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>B</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>B</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>B</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>B</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>B</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>B</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=15 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=15 class=xl6421017 style='height:15.0pt;border-top:none'>C</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>C</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>C</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>C</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>C</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>C</td>
  <td class=xl6421017 style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>C</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=15 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=15 class=xl6521017 align=right style='height:15.0pt;border-top:
  none'>1</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>4</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>5</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>6</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>7</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=15 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=15 class=xl6521017 align=right style='height:15.0pt;border-top:
  none'>1</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>4</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>5</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>6</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>7</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=15 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=15 class=xl6521017 align=right style='height:15.0pt;border-top:
  none'>1</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>4</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>5</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>6</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>7</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=15 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=15 class=xl6521017 align=right style='height:15.0pt;border-top:
  none'>1</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>4</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>5</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>6</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>7</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=15 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=15 class=xl6521017 align=right style='height:15.0pt;border-top:
  none'>1</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>4</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>5</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>6</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>7</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=15 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=15 class=xl6521017 align=right style='height:15.0pt;border-top:
  none'>1</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>4</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>5</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>6</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>7</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=15 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=15 class=xl6521017 align=right style='height:15.0pt;border-top:
  none'>1</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>4</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>5</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>6</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>7</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=15 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=15 class=xl6521017 align=right style='height:15.0pt;border-top:
  none'>1</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>4</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>5</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>6</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>7</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=15 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=15 class=xl6521017 align=right style='height:15.0pt;border-top:
  none'>1</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>4</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>5</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>6</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>7</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=15 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=15 class=xl6521017 align=right style='height:15.0pt;border-top:
  none'>1</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>4</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>5</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>6</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>7</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=15 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=15 class=xl6521017 align=right style='height:15.0pt;border-top:
  none'>1</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>4</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>5</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>6</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>7</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=15 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=15 class=xl6521017 align=right style='height:15.0pt;border-top:
  none'>1</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>2</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>3</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>4</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>5</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>6</td>
  <td class=xl6521017 align=right style='border-top:none;border-left:none'>7</td>
 </tr>
 <![if supportMisalignedColumns]>
 <tr height=0 style='display:none'>
  <td width=48 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=48 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=48 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=48 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=48 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=48 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=48 style='width:48pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <![endif]>
</table>

</div>


<!----------------------------->
<!--END OF OUTPUT FROM EXCEL PUBLISH AS WEB PAGE WIZARD-->
<!----------------------------->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: do you think the row highlight can be changed to just WHITE BORDER SURROUNDING ALL OF THE active row?